# Show id when div is halfway up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I know how to actually get `id`s and classes and do the basics but I'm not sure how to do this:
 "When the user scrolls down, the title of the post that takes up half the screen should be shown."

The setup is supposed to look something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GkrCU/1/)...
   Any ideas?

Comment: Here's what you might looking for: http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-element-onscreen-visibility/194/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JS and I used jQuery to do a simple prototype

It's all about listening to the `scroll` event and dealing with the offset of the elements from top you need to add a simple condition for the heights but now it's just working fine

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var scrolledTop = $(this).scrollTop(); 
    console.log(scrolledTop); 
    $(".blog").each(function(){
        if($(this).offset().top < scrolledTop)
        {
            $('#blogname').html($(this).html()); 
        }

    }); 
});
```

Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/GkrCU/2/

I hope this can help :)

Comment: OMG yes, thank you;
here is an edited version that fits the bill:
http://jsfiddle.net/GkrCU/5/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     var windowheight = $(this).scrollTop();
     $(".blog").each(function () {
         var sc = $(this).offset().top;
         var id = $(this).attr('id');



         if (sc < windowheight) {
             $("#blogname span").html(id)
         }
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GkrCU/1/